# How does logical operators behave?

Tags: shell, logical-operators

I am trying to understand this code in shell script however i am not able to understand the logic here. Can anyone help me understand the logic behind this..

```
(( 0 && 1 )) **# Logical AND** echo $? # 1 ***
# And so ... let "num = (( 0 && 1 ))" echo $num # 0
# But ... let "num = (( 0 && 1 ))" echo $? # 1 ***

(( 200 || 11 )) **# Logical OR**
echo $? # 0 ***
# ...
let "num = (( 200 || 11 ))"
echo $num # 1
let "num = (( 200 || 11 ))"
echo $? # 0 ***
```

Question:

1. Why did the shell returned a exit status of 1 on execution of (( 0
   && 1 ))? 
   On execution of let "num = (( 0 && 1 ))" why do we get
   different exit status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(( 0 && 1 ))` is returning exist status of `1` because any `0 && $any_number` operation will always be zero and that will make exist status of `((...))` as `1`.

However when you assign value of `(( 0 && 1 ))` to another shell variable using:

```
let "num = (( 0 && 1 ))"
```

then exit status will be `0` since assignment is successful and command is considered a success.